# Show current calendar week in menu bar?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, calendar, menu-bar

Is there a way to get macOS to display the current calendar week in the menu bar, maybe as part of the date or as an additional information elsewhere in the menu bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Itsycal](https://www.mowglii.com/itsycal/) by Mowglii (I'm not affiliated with the company or software).  It's free, open source, and allows you to format the displayed date/time [many different ways](https://www.mowglii.com/itsycal/datetime.html).

[image]

Comment: Likewise, if it was a good question it's easier to spot it for others if it has a vote ;-)

Comment: An answer that helps the OP and is accepted but still gets a downvoted a year later with no comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Day-O](https://shauninman.com/archive/2016/10/20/day_o_2_mac_menu_bar_clock) calendar app to display custom date format in menubar. In Day-O preferences add `w` for the week of year.

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you for the great suggestion. In the end I decided to go with the open source alternative Itsycal.